# When moving from one view to another the latter one is not processed

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

So i am having a dlist view that displays a list of fields with checkboxes from which to choose. The chosen field returns the entire row that is sent via a submit button to the edit template for further processing. Here is the dlist view and its form:

```
def dlist(request):
...
if "_edit" in request.POST:
    print "You pressed update button in list template"
    form = selectForm2(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        print "selectForm VALID!"
        delete_items = form.cleaned_data['select_fields']
        for item in delete_items:
            instance = model_class.objects.get(**{field_list[2]:item})
            instance_list.append(item)      
        messages.success(request, 'Selected fields updated')
        return render(request, 'Directories/edit.html', {"field_names": field_names, "instance_list": instance_list, ...})
    else:
            return HttpResponse('ERROR in POST -- Return to form submission')

class selectForm2(forms.Form):
    select_fields = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=fields())

# the choices for the form. It is a list of field ('descr_en') values.
def fields():
    m_values = Attributes.objects.values_list('descr_en', flat=True)
    for val in m_values:
        field_classes.append((val, val))
    return field_classes
```

and its template

```
*list.html*
...
<form action="" method="post">  {% csrf_token %}
<tbody>
{% with field_names|slice:"1:" as sliced_fnames %}      
    <tr>
    {% for f_name in sliced_fnames %}
            {% if f_name = sliced_fnames.0 %}
                <td>
                   {{form.as_p}} 
                </td>   
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

{% endwith %}
</tbody>
</table> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Update selected items" name="_edit" />
</form>
```

Now when the "_edit" submit button is pressed I should be redirected to the edit template and the modelEdit view and see the first message printed as seen below:

```
def modelEdit(request):
    print "seems like u pressed the edit button!"
    updated_item = request.POST.get('select_fields')
    print "updated_item", updated_item
    ...
    return render(request, 'Directories/edit.html')
```

However this does not happen and nothing is displayed instead. Still, the dictionaries passed from the dlist view (field_names, instance_list) through selectForm are rendered in the edit.html:

```
*edit.html*
<div id="content" align="center">
<h3> Update entry</h3> 
<br />
{{m_tb_name}}
{% if instance_list %}
    {% for instance in instance_list %}
        {{instance}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {% for f_name in field_names %} 
        {% if not forloop.first %}      
           {% for instance in instance_list %}
                {{f_name}}: <input id="edit-{{f_name}}" value="{{instance}}" type="text" name={{f_name}} /><br />
           {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}<br />
    <input type="submit" name="_alter" value="Update" />
    <input type="reset" name="Clear" value="Clear" />
</form> 
</div>
```

And lastly, here is my urls.py file:

```
*urls.py*
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from Directories import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^list$', views.dlist, name='list_models'),
url(r'^edit$', views.modelEdit, name='edit_models'),
...
)
```

So when I manually edit the URL in my browser as Directories/edit I see the printed message from my view but when I try to reach the edit.html throught the "_edit" button in list.html it renders the edit template but does not process the view (modelEdit) for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply rendering the Directories/edit.html, not invoking the view. You can verify that using a print statement in the modelEdit.
Instead what you might need is

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/edit')
```

This will invoke your views.

Comment: yes, that is right! i thought render() was both rendering the template and invoking the view... seems i was wrong. It worked! Thanks a lot!